# Relational Database: When do we need to add more entities?

Tags: database, entity, relationship, relational

We had a discussion today related to W3 lecture case study about how many entities we need for each situation. And I have some confusion as below:

Case 1) An employee is assigned to be a member of a team. A team with more than 5 members will have a team leader. The members of the team elect the team leader. List the entity(s) which you can identify in the above statement? In this cases, if we don't create 2 entities for above requirement, we need to add two more attributes for each employee which can lead to anomaly issues later. Therefore, we need to have 2 entities as below:

EMPLOYEE (PK is employeeId) (0-M)----------------(0-1) TEAM (PK teamId&employeeId) -> 2 entities

Case 2) The company also introduced a mentoring program, whereby a new employee will be paired with someone who has been in the company longer." How many entity/ies do you need to model the mentoring program?

The Answer from Lecturer is 1. With that, we have to add 2 more attributes for each Employee, mentorRole (Mentor or Mentee) and pairNo (to distinguish between different pairs and to know who mentors whom), doesn't it?

My question is why can't we create a new Entity named MENTORING which will be similar to TEAM in Q1? And why we can only do that if this is a many-many relationship?

EMPLOYEE (PK is employeeId) (0-M)----------------(0-1) TEAM (PK is pairNo&employeeId) -> 2 entities

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. In the first case, I'd have Employee, Team, and TeamMember as 3 entities, with either an optional TeamLeader column in the Team, or an IsLeader flag on the TeamMember table with a unique constraint on TeamID, IsLeader.

Comment: On the second question, I'd probably just add a column to the Employee table to contain MentorID, which is a reference to another Employee row (the employee's mentor).

Comment: Entitiy vs relationship vs attribute is an unnecessary distinction imposed by athough fundamental to the E-R model. The relational model just represents relationships on zero or more values, and there's always *some* entity identifiable with *every superkey/unique subrow of every posible query result*. (Eg marriage-cost pairs for tuesday pm marriages involving left-handed non-salaried sentient employees.) Satisfy the rules of the method you are following. Don't expect a unique solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules for defining entities, attributes, and relationships in an ER-Diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485554/what-are-the-basic-rules-for-defining-entities-attributes-and-relationships-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, about terminology: I use entity to mean an individual person, thing or event. You and I are two distinct entities, but since we're both members of StackOverflow, we're part of the same entity *set*. Entity sets are contrasted with value sets in the ER model, while the relational model has no such distinction.

1. While you're right about the number of entity sets, there's some issues with your implementation. TEAM's PK shouldn't be `teamId, employeeId`, it should be only `teamId`. The EMPLOYEE table should have a `teamId` foreign key (not part of the PK) to indicate team membership. The `employeeId` column in the TEAM table could be used to represent the team leader and is dependent on the `teamId` (since each team can have only one leader at most).

   With only one entity set, we would probably represent team membership and leadership as:

   `EMPLOYEE(employeeId PK, team, leader)`

   where `team` is some team name or number which has to be the same for team members, and `leader` is a true/false column to indicate whether the employee in that row is the leader of his/her team. A problem with this model is that we can't ensure that a team has only one leader.
2. Again, there's some issues with the implementation. I don't see the need to identify pairs apart from the employees involved, and having a `mentorRole` (mentor or mentee) indicates that the association will be recorded for both mentor and mentee. This is redundant and creates an opportunity for inconsistency. If the goal was to represent a one-to-one relationship, there are better ways. I suggest a separate table `MENTORING(menteeEmployeeId PK, mentorEmployeeId UQ)` (or possibly a unique but nullable `mentorEmployeeId` in the EMPLOYEE table, depending on how your DBMS handles nulls in unique indexes).

The difference between the two cases is that teams can have any number of members and one leader, which is most effectively implemented by identifying teams separately from employees, whereas mentorship is a simpler association that is sufficiently identified by either of the two people involved (provided you consistently use the same role as identifier). You could create a separate entity set for mentoring, with relationships to the employees involved - it might look like my MENTORING table but with an additional surrogate key as PK, but there's no need for the extra identifier.

> And why we can only do that if this is a many-many relationship?

What do you mean? Your examples don't contain a many-to-many relationship and we don't create additional entity sets for many-to-many relationships. If you're thinking of so-called "bridge" tables, you've got some concepts mixed up. Entity sets aren't tables. An entity set is a set of values, a table represents a relation over one or more sets of values. In Chen's original method, *all* relationships were represented in separate tables. It's just that we've gotten used to denormalizing simple one-to-one and one-to-many relationships into the same tables as entity attributes, but we can't do the same for many-to-many binary relationships or ternary and higher relationships in general.

Comment: And the rub with any data modelling question - we have to tease out some of the details. So in the answer here by @reaanb, each employee can only be a member of one team. Is that a business rule or can a person be in multiple teams? If its the latter then you cant have TeamID in the Employee table, need to be a separate TeamMember table. All this is the job of a data modeller, and can almost never be answered by the initial specs we are given. You just have to keep asking! But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Good point, TomC. In this case, the cardinality indicators in the example: `(0-M)----------------(0-1)` showed that for each employee, only a single team was appropriate.

Comment: I didn't see that mixed into the description. Wasnt the clearest spec I've ever seen :)